# How to use shared library in websphere liberty profile

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

It seems simple but ...

I'm just starting to learn liberty profile.

I can't use shared library.

here's documentation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html

so in server.xml I put (and restart server), for example:

```
<library>
    <folder dir="C:/libs/gson/"></folder>
    <!-- or even <file name="C:/libs/gson/gson-2.3.1.jar" /> -->
</library>
```

Anyway at runtime I receive: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson"

On a servlet I just have the import and a simple use:

```
...    
import com.google.gson.Gson;
...

@WebServlet("/")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    ...

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Serialization
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ...
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: as a side note, if you enable the `jsonb-1.0` feature you can perform JSON [de]serialization with the `javax.json.bind.*` APIs and you don't need to manually include/configure Gson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part you are missing is that the application needs to be configured to reference the library. There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use the Global shared library as described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_global_libs.html

Then, simply change your library ID to `global` like this:

```xml
<library id="global">
```

2. Give your library an ID and add a `<classloader commonLibraryRef="..."/>` as described in @njr's answer

Answer (score 8):

Adding a library element to server configuration doesn't automatically make it available to applications.  You need to configure the application to have access to the library, for example,

```
<application location="myapp.war">
  <classloader commonLibraryRef="gsonLib"/>
</application>

<library id="gsonLib">
    <file name="C:/libs/gson/gson-2.3.1.jar" />
</library>
```

Comment: Yes... I forgot this step... thinking on traditional WebSphere corresponds to these steps: "Server -> Server Types -> WebSphere Application Servers -> [server] -> Java and Process Management -> Class loader -> [Classloader] -> Shared library references -> Add" ... In the future thinking the exact steps of traditional WebSphere should help to not forget steps, or solve issue like this one